# While trying to hide submit button until all input fields are valid it is hiding only for the first text filed validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Working on form validation i'am trying to hide submit button until all text and password fields are not null and satisfies all input validation, but the problem is, it is enabling the submit button for the first text field validation only.

So what's wrong with my code, please correct me.,

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var error_firstName = false;
var error_lastName = false;
var error_emailAdd = false;
var error_pass = false;
var error_confirmPass = false;
var error_mobile = false;
var error_confirmMob = false;   

$("#error_form_firstName").hide();
$("#error_form_lastName").hide();
$("#error_form_emailAdd").hide();
$("#error_form_password").hide();
$("#error_span").hide();
$("#error_form_confirmPassword").hide();
$("#error_form_mobile").hide();
$("error_form_confirmNumber").hide();

$("#formSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled");

$("#form_firstName").focusout(function() {
    check_FirstName();
});

$("#form_lastName").focusout(function() {
    check_LastName();
});

$("#form_email").focusout(function() {
    check_email();
});

$("#form_pass").focusout(function() {
    check_password();
});

$("#form_cPass").focusout(function() {
    check_confirm_password();
});

$("#form_mob").focusout(function() {
    check_Mobile();
});

$("#form_cMob").focusout(function() {
    check_cMobile();
});

$('input, password').change(function(){
if(error_firstName == false && error_lastName == false && error_emailAdd == false && error_pass == false && error_confirmPass == false && error_mobile == false && error_confirmMob == false){
        $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
            return true;
        }
        else{
            alert("Please fill the form correctly");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Corresponding HTML code for form validation:

```
<form:form id="reg_form" action="submitRegistration.do" method="POST"
                commandName="registrationForm">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 register-top-grid">
                    <h3>Please fill the below information</h3>
                    <div>
                        <span>First Name</span>
                        <form:input id="form_firstName" path="firstName" />
                        <form:errors path="firstName" cssStyle="color:red" element="div" />
                        <p id="error_form_firstName" class="errorMessage"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Last Name</span>
                        <form:input id="form_lastName" path="lastName" />
                        <form:errors path="lastName" cssStyle="color:red" element="div" />
                        <p id="error_form_lastName" class="errorMessage"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Email Address</span>
                        <form:input id="form_email" path="email" />
                        <form:errors path="email" cssStyle="color:red" element="div" />
                        <p id="error_form_emailAdd" class="errorMessage"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Password</span>
                        <form:password id="form_pass" path="password" />
                        <form:errors path="password" cssStyle="color:red" element="div" />
                        <p id="error_form_password" class="errorMessage"></p>

                        <!-- This is for extra line after password for alignment of error_text -->
                        <p id="error_span" class="errorMessage"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Confirm Password</span>
                        <form:password id="form_cPass" path="confirmPassword" />
                        <form:errors path="confirmPassword" cssStyle="color:red" element="div" />
                        <p id="error_form_confirmPassword" class="errorMessage"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Mobile Number</span>
                        <form:input id="form_mob" path="mobile" />
                        <form:errors path="mobile" cssStyle="color:red" element="div" />
                        <p id="error_form_mobile" class="errorMessage"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Confirm Mobile Number</span>
                        <form:input id="form_cMob" path="confirmMobile" />
                        <form:errors path="confirmMobile" cssStyle="color:red" element="div" />
                        <p id="error_form_confirmNumber" class="errorMessage"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="text-align: center">
                        <input id="formSubmit" type="submit" value="submit" /> <button id="clear" type="button" value="clear" />
                    </div>
                    <a class="news-letter" href="#"> <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked=""><i> </i>Sign Up for Newsletter</label>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </form:form>
```

Comment: Hard to guess without corresponding HTML code, but have you tried using the same selector for the `removeAttr` as for the `attr`, i.e. `#formSubmit` instead of `input[type=submit]`? BTW If not sure what a selector gets, you an always console.log it's result, like `console.log($("input[type=submit]"))`

Comment: Note that `error_firstName == false` can also be `!error_firstName`.   Your code is incomplete as posted, missing the closing `});` on the document ready event handler.  Which then brings up the question, are those globals inside there (for the booleans)  referenced/set to true inside that same scope?  (those functions...)?  Normally you check `hange` events on inputs rather than `focusout`.

Comment: @TomášVarga i have tried the same same id #formSubmit as well but i doesn't made any change and i have included the corresponding html code please take a look

Comment: Why two submit inputs on the form?  Should that second one be `type='button'`?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss yes i missed it here now mentioned it, and i handled those global variables properly but still i'am confused why it is checking the first field and coming out from the condition

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss yes u r correct i have modified it too, but correct me with the logic as well

Comment: Curious, why all the "form" prefix as in `form:input` in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF I am reading this correctly, you have a function for each input to check THAT ONE INPUT when you focus out.  Now assume you have First Name and it is OK after entry - your 'Last Name' has not yet been entered/checked; yet you have negative errors (all set false) by default.  I would suggest to set them all to `true` instead - so that they are all entered before the submit gets enabled.  I make assumption that all elements are required.

Optionally, on one "focusout", trigger that focusout event on ALL of them, but that is a good bit of extra code on each focus out.

Another option would be to have a "validateform" function and use that for all of them i.e.

```
var error_firstName = true;
var error_lastName = true;
var error_emailAdd = true;
var error_pass = true;
var error_confirmPass = true;
var error_mobile = true;
var error_confirmMob = true;   

function validateform(){
  check_FirstName();
  check_LastName();
  check_email();
  // the others in here...
  // now do this
  var hasErrors = error_firstName 
        || error_lastName 
        || error_emailAdd 
        || error_pass 
        || error_confirmPass
        || error_mobile 
        || error_confirmMob;
  if(hasErrors){alert("Please fill the form correctly");}
  $("#formSubmit").prop("disabled", hasErrors");
  return hasErrors;
}
// add others in here
$("#form_firstName,#form_lastName,#form_email")
  .on("focusout change",validateform);
```

Note you could also do a bulk show/hide of your error things like this:

```
function displayErrorThings(){
    $("#error_form_firstName").toggle(error_firstName);
    $("#error_form_lastName").toggle(error_lastName);
    $("#error_form_emailAdd").toggle(error_emailAdd);
    $("#error_form_password").toggle(error_pass);
    $("#error_span").toggle(error_pass);
    $("#error_form_confirmPassword").toggle(error_confirmPass);
    $("#error_form_mobile").toggle(error_mobile);
    $("error_form_confirmNumber").toggle(error_confirmMob);
}
```

Thus just call it in the same validation function above (and on initial start)

```
displayErrorThings()
```

Comment: awsome, thank you man crack that one though added extra things but you lead me to it!!!